How to set default_order_line when opening sale order form? something went wrong in 'default_order_line
def action_create_sale_order(self):
    self.ensure_one()

    if not self.product_ids:
        raise ValidationError("Please select a product to create a Sale Order.")

    return {
        'name': 'Sale Order',
        'view_mode': 'form',
        'res_model': 'sale.order',
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'target': 'new',
        'context': {
            'default_partner_id': self.partner_id.id,
            'default_order_line': [(0, 0, {'product_id': product.id, 'product_uom_qty': 1}) for product in
                                   self.product_ids],
            'default_helpdesk_ticket_id': self.id,
        },
    }

This solution looks simple and makes sense. However,matter what field I pass to order line it doesn't work

Rep isn't high enough to comment but it would've been better if you had elaborated on what "doesn't work" entails: Did it fail with an error message, fail with no error message, wrong sale.order.line record was created?
Since we don't know what model you are working with (and consequently what record self could be) or what views this function would be used in, you should check that:

Your view actually has a button that calls upon this function.
Your model/record actually has a product_ids field and can be set from whatever view you are using the button in.

